# Jave Reading Video/Audio Codecs From File

Tags: java, file, video, io

I have a folder of mixed video files (multiple formats for web display mp4, ogv, webm). When retrieving those files in Java I can verify the format by pulling the extension from the filename. **Is there a way to retrieve other information such as video and audio codec data from the file?**

To create the files I am using ffmpeg from within Java to transcode video files to the formats and sizes I need, so when the file is being created I do know the codec information. **If its not automatically stored somewhere in the file, is there a way to set metadata or something and store the info manually so I can retrieve it later?** I am not using a database to store file locations or other data, just simply scanning and retrieving from the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video and audio data streams (e.g. H.264/AVC video, AAC, Dolby Digital audio, etc.) are multiplexed (or 'muxed') together inside file formats that are known as a container formats.  MP4 is one such container format and is designed to be able to hold many different types of video and audio stream (see http://www.mp4ra.org/codecs.html for some of the officially registered types).

The different container formats have metadata that identifies the different media streams that are contained so as to help determine what type of decoder should be used to decode a particular media stream.

If you can (you said you're using Java),  try using [ffprobe](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) to determine the container, video and audio formats used in a media file (plus other metadata).  It may not be 100% reliable for all media types (as it may not recognise some) but given that you are encoding with ffmpeg (ffprobe is an ffmpeg-derived tool) it should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

I think `ffmpeg` can automatically obtain video and audio formats from the files you specify as a source for `ffmpeg` utility.

If you need the metadata for other purposes then you can try Red5 server sources (java). There are a lot of readers (including `MP4Reader`) that can be used to obtain metadata.

For example for **mp4** files `MP4Reader` scans the entire file in class constructor and then you can obtain metadata from the first tag:

```
reader = new org.red5.io.mp4.impl.MP4Reader(myFile)
String v = reader.getVideoCodecId();  // e.g. "avc1" (for h.254), "VP6F"
String a = reader.getAudioCodecId();  // e.g. "mp4a" (for aac), ".mp3" (for mp3)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no easy way to determine file type by content.  You have to make assumptions and then test those assumptions with code (e.g. I think it's type X so I'll inspect the first Y bytes for the pattern that always is present in files of type X.)